# What is the meaning of datetime values less than datetime.min?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

What is happening here?

This expected:

```
>>> datetime.min - timedelta(days=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Unexpected:

```
>>> datetime.min - timedelta(days=2)
datetime.datetime(1, 0, 255, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.min > (datetime.min - timedelta(days=2))
True
```

In python, what do these values mean when you subtract from datetime.min? What dates do they represent? Why do some cases not trigger an OverflowError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to upgrade to Python 2.6 or later, which fixed this bug.

```
$ python2.5 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.min - datetime.timedelta(days=2))'
0001-00-255 00:00:00
$ python2.6 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.min - datetime.timedelta(days=2))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: date value out of range
$ python2.7 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.min - datetime.timedelta(days=2))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: date value out of range
$ python3.3 -c 'import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.min - datetime.timedelta(days=2))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Do you need someone to track down the bug number, patch, and python-dev discussion, or is that enough information for you?

Comment: Ah, that is perfect. I never even occurred to me that it would be a *bug in the interpreter*! Thank you!

Comment: My python is version 2.6.5, incidentally, but I know where to go from here.

Comment: Well, it's probably a bug in the standard library, not in the interpreter… Also, it never occurred to me that it would have been fixed between 2.6.5 and 2.6.7 (the 2.6 I used above), but now that I think about it, it's just as plausible as it being fixed between 2.5 and 2.6…

Comment: this is still happening on python 3.4